# How do I add dynamic WHERE clause for search filtering?

Tags: php, sql-server

I have 7 search parameters although the code below shows only two, Title and Type.

We would like to give our users the ability to search by ANY of the 7 parameters.

They should also be given the ability to search by more than one parameter.

How would I adapt the code below to use a dynamic $where clause?

Example, a user could select where type='some value'.

A user should also be able to select where type='some value' and title='some value'.

Thank you in advance.

```
function ms_escape_string($data) {
        if ( !isset($data) or empty($data) ) return '';
        if ( is_numeric($data) ) return $data;

        $non_displayables = array(
            '/%0[0-8bcef]/',            // url encoded 00-08, 11, 12, 14, 15
            '/%1[0-9a-f]/',             // url encoded 16-31
            '/[\x00-\x08]/',            // 00-08
            '/\x0b/',                   // 11
            '/\x0c/',                   // 12
            '/[\x0e-\x1f]/'             // 14-31
        );
        foreach ( $non_displayables as $regex )
            $data = preg_replace( $regex, '', $data );
        $data = str_replace("'", "''", $data );
        return $data;
    }

    $strprojectTitle = null;
    $strbidType = null;
    if(isset($_POST["projectTitle"]))
    {
        $strprojectTitle = $_POST["projectTitle"];
    }
    if(isset($_POST["BidType"]))
    {
        $strbidType = $_POST["BidType"];
    }

?>

<?php

   $sql = "Select b.ID,convert(char(10),b.BidDate,101) BidDate,convert(char(10),
          b.DueDate,101)DueDate,b.BidTitle,b.DueTime,b.BidID,BidIDFile,
          d.Department,b.BidType,CASE WHEN b.AwardDate ='01/01/1900' Then NULL ELSe convert(char(10),b.AwardDate,101)END AS AwardDate,
          convert(char(10),b.LastUpdate,101) LastUpdate,s.Status
          FROM bids b inner join dept d on b.Department=d.DeptID inner join Status s on b.BidStatus=s.StatusId WHERE b.BidTitle = ' . ms_escape_string($strprojectTitle) . ' OR b.BidType = ' . ms_escape_string($strbidType) . ' ";
```

///****Latest attempt

```
$fields = array(
    'projectTitle' => 'b.BidTitle',
    'BidType' => 'b.BidType'
);

$where = array();
foreach($fields as $fieldPost => $fieldDb) {
    if(isset($_POST[$fieldPost]) && strlen($_POST[$fieldPost]) > 0) {
        $where[] = "`$fieldDb` = '$_POST[$fieldPost]'";
    }
}

   $sql = "Select b.ID,convert(char(10),b.BidDate,101) BidDate,convert(char(10),
          b.DueDate,101)DueDate,b.BidTitle,b.DueTime,b.BidID,BidIDFile,
          d.Department,b.BidType,CASE WHEN b.AwardDate ='01/01/1900' Then NULL ELSe convert(char(10),b.AwardDate,101)END AS AwardDate,
          convert(char(10),b.LastUpdate,101) LastUpdate,s.Status
          FROM bids b inner join dept d on b.Department=d.DeptID inner join Status s on b.BidStatus=s.StatusId
          " . ( count($where) > 0 ? " WHERE " . implode(' AND ', $where) : "" );
```

Comment: query builder or if statements :)

Comment: You can have a Stored procedure with optional parameters have a look at this answer [`Stored procedure big where clause or multiple procedures`](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93494/stored-procedure-big-where-clause-or-multiple-procedures/93496#93496)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this part in your code:

```
$strprojectTitle = null;
$strbidType = null;
if(isset($_POST["projectTitle"]))
{
    $strprojectTitle = $_POST["projectTitle"];
}
if(isset($_POST["BidType"]))
{
    $strbidType = $_POST["BidType"];
}
```

And replace it with the one below, which enables a dynamic way of building the WHERE conditions:

```
## easily add here the fields you have
$fields = array(
    'projectTitle' => 'b.BidTitle',
    'BidType' => 'b.BidType'
);

$where = array();
foreach($fields as $fieldPost => $fieldDb) {
    if(isset($_POST[$fieldPost]) && strlen($_POST[$fieldPost]) > 0) {
        $where[] = "`$fieldDb` = '" . ms_escape_string($_POST[$fieldPost]) . "'";
    }
}

## Use the $where array in your final SQL query
## important to test if count($where) > 0 in case no search has been made
$sql = "SELECT ..... " . ( count($where) > 0 ? " WHERE " . implode(' AND ', $where) : "" );
```

A more advanced example to build the WHERE string by supporting multiple search types (for example the search comparators: LIKE %..% and =)

```
## support multiple search comparators
$fields = array(
    'projectTitle' => array('field' => 'b.BidTitle', 'searchType' => 'like'),
    'BidType' => array('field' => 'b.BidType', 'searchType' => 'equal')
);

$where = array();
foreach($fields as $fieldPost => $field) {
    if(isset($_POST[$fieldPost]) && strlen($_POST[$fieldPost]) > 0) {
        if($field['searchType'] == 'like') {
            $where[] = "`".$field['field']."` LIKE '%" . ms_escape_string($_POST[$fieldPost]) . "%'";
        } else {
            $where[] = "`".$field['field']."` = '" . ms_escape_string($_POST[$fieldPost]) . "'";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would probably use `AND` when imploding

Comment: @engine9pw, WOW, incredible responses.

Just a question, I love the more advanced option but does this means that `'BidType' => array('field' => 'b.BidType', 'searchType' => 'equal')` the BidType is the form field, not the db. The db fieldname is b.BidType.

Please bear with the newbiew.

Thank you all very much.

Comment: Hi, you're welcome. I'm glad you like the solution. I just took the db field name from your original query: OR b.BidType = ....... You can use anything you like there.

Comment: @engine9pw, Hi please see my latest post at top of page.

I am running into an error that says: `Warning: sqlsrv_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in ...`

For now, I have removed the ms_escapte_String() function. It is giving me problem. I will reinstate it once I get the code working.

Giorgos, thanks a lot for your efforts. I wanted something similar to what engin9pw is giving me. It uses AND only when invoked. Otherwise, use the filter the user wants.

Please bear with me guys.

Comment: You can try and debug your query. Display only the query string (echo $sql), see if you can spot any errors and even run it in a separate SQL client.